# How do I change a hidden input value with Selenium using Python

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I'm trying to change the daterange-begin\end values as seen in the HTML below.

```
<input type="hidden" name="lsSCurrent Begin Date:" value="05/01/2020" id="daterange-begin">
<input type="hidden" name="lsSCurrent End Date:" value="05/05/2020" id="daterange-end">
```

Here is my Python code.

```
driver.find_element_by_id('daterange-begin').send_keys('05/01/2020')
```

I ultimately end up getting the error below:

selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.138)

A little more context. The value is associated with a date picker that pops up. The date picker is clearly visible before the code is executed and looks like the picture below.

I'm open to other solutions. I can only share so much of the HTML since it's a hidden website.

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute some JavaScript code:

```
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].value="05/01/2020"', driver.find_element_by_id('daterange-begin'))
```